# Location based UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I am working on a piece of functionality that would allow an iOS user to swipe the left half of the screen and trigger a method.  The UISwipeGestureRecognizers are called in the ViewController.m file and the methods selected by those recognizers are in MyScene.m.

I can get this to work without the swipe location provision but I have not found a successful way to make it only trigger on the left half of the screen.  I have included some code below that show examples for with and without the location requirement.

ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    if (!skView.scene) {
        skView.showsFPS = YES;
        skView.showsNodeCount = YES;

        SKScene *scene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
        [skView presentScene:scene];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(scene) action:@selector(screenSwipedRight)];
        swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        swipeRight.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeRight)];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(scene) action:@selector(screenSwipedLeft)];
        swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        swipeLeft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeLeft)];

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUp = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(scene) action:@selector(screenSwipedUp)];
        swipeUp.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        swipeUp.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:(swipeUp)];
    }
}
```

MyScene.m:

```
-(void)screenSwipedRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipedRight
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [swipedRight locationInView:(self.view)];
    NSInteger movePlayer;
    if (touchPoint.x <=self.view.bounds.size.width/2) {
        movePlayer = 1;
    } else {
        movePlayer = 2;
    }
    if (movePlayer ==1) {
        CGFloat percentToRight = 1-(self.playerOne.position.x / self.view.bounds.size.width);
        NSTimeInterval timeToRight = self.horizontalRunSpeed * percentToRight;
        NSLog(@"Percent to right = %f",percentToRight);
        NSLog(@"Time to right = %f",timeToRight);
        SKAction *moveNodeRight = [SKAction moveToX:self.view.bounds.size.width-self.playerOne.size.width duration:timeToRight];
        [self.playerOne runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[moveNodeRight]]];
    }
}

-(void)screenSwipedLeft
{
    NSLog(@"Screen was swiped to the left");
    CGFloat percentToLeft = self.playerOne.position.x / self.view.bounds.size.width;
    NSTimeInterval timeToLeft = self.horizontalRunSpeed * percentToLeft;
    NSLog(@"Percent to left = %f",percentToLeft);
    NSLog(@"Time to left = %f",timeToLeft);
    SKAction *moveNodeLeft = [SKAction moveToX:self.playerOne.size.width duration:timeToLeft];
    [self.playerOne runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[moveNodeLeft]]];
}

-(void)screenSwipedUp
{
    NSLog(@"Screen was swiped up");

    [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{ self.physicsWorld.gravity = self.antiGravityAmount;}],[SKAction waitForDuration:.25],[SKAction runBlock:^{ self.physicsWorld.gravity = self.gravityAmount;}]]]];
}
```

The swipedRight method is where I am attempting to differentiate between swipe locations.

Executing this code results in a signal SIGABRT error, but only when I swipe to the right.  Swiping left or up continue to work as they normally would.  It may have something to do with the choice of view from "locationInView" but I could be entirely wrong.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thank you for your help.

**Edit: Here is the log file on the error -**

2014-01-04 18:10:32.316 Romp[584:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x976afe0  (not loaded)

2014-01-04 18:10:32.375 Romp[584:70b] viewDidLoad was run

2014-01-04 18:10:32.425 Romp[584:70b] Size: {480, 320}

2014-01-04 18:10:32.427 Romp[584:70b] Screen initialized

2014-01-04 18:10:33.917 Romp[584:70b] -[MyScene screenSwipedRight]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9995790

2014-01-04 18:10:33.920 Romp[584:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyScene screenSwipedRight]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9995790'

*** First throw call stack:

(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0185e5e4 **exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x015e18b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x018fb903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0184e90b __*forwarding*** + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0184e4ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x005a8e8c _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 230
    6   UIKit                               0x005a7b00 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 383
    7   UIKit                               0x005a956d -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] + 60
    8   UIKit                               0x005acacd **_UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke + 57
    9   UIKit                               0x005aca4e _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 317
    10  UIKit                               0x005a3148 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 199
    11  UIKit                               0x0026f19a -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1291
    12  UIKit                               0x002700ba -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1030
    13  UIKit                               0x00243e86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    14  UIKit                               0x0022e18f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x017e783f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 15
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x017e71cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0180429e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01803ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x018038db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x038039e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x03803809 GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x00230d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    23  Romp                                0x0000615d main + 141
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x01e9c70d start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Comment: on what line exactly does the error occur?

Comment: Thread 1 Queue: com.apple.main-thread.... @autoreleasepool { return UIApplicationMain (argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass [AppDelegate] Class.  Adding the log file to my post for additional info as well.

Comment: As far as I understand the problem is you are trying to get MyScene's view in the method by typing self.view . Instead you should use the swipeRight.view

Comment: Changing to swipedRight.view resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'-[MyScene screenSwipedRight]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9995790'
```

Pretty standard error. You do this:

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight =
     [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:(scene) 
                                               action:@selector(screenSwipedRight)];
```

You registered a `@selector(screenSwipedRight)` as callback which is a method that takes no parameters. This method does not exist in your code.

Your method has the same name but it takes an additional argument of `UISwipeGestureRecognizer*` which makes this a different method. So you need to register it as `@selector(screenSwipedRight:)`. Notice the colon at the end.

PS: enable [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) in your app. That will have Xcode show you the line of code when an exception like this one occurs. Takes a lot of guesswork out of debugging.

Comment: This worked perfectly and was very well explained.  Thanks for taking the time to help!